# Java Comparable and Interface

Tags: java

Lets Say you have ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, and interfaceA.

ClassA and ClassB implements interfaceA, The classC contains a List< interface >

Now lets say we add some values from ClassA and ClassB into ClassC List

What happens if ClassA implement different comparable method CompareTo than ClassB, and we call Collection.sort(list< interface >)

which CompareTo will be applied to sort the list ? or we must have the same CompareTo method in every Class that implement interfaceA

Answer (score 0):

The Comparable interface is not a best approach. I would recommend using a Comparator passed into the Collection sort method.

Comment: Thats what i thought so we can have the same sorting algorithm on every object on the list

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to run such code. Imagine you have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Number<T extends Number<T>> implements Comparable<T> {}
```

and two classes which extend it:

```
public class One extends Number<One> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(One o) {
        return -1;
    }
}

public class Two extends Number<Two> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Two o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then execution of the following snippet:

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new One());
list.add(new Two());
Collections.sort((List<Number>) list);
```

will throw a ClassCastException

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: comparable.One cannot be cast to comparable.Two
> ```

In general your idea breaks the contract of the compareTo method (See Joshua Bloch *Effective Java*, Item 12):

> - The implementor must ensure  sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all  x  and  y .
> - The  implementor  must  also  ensure  that  the relation  is  transitive:   (x.com- pareTo(y) > 0 && y.compareTo(z) > 0)  implies  x.compareTo(z) > 0.
> - Finally, the implementor must ensure that  x.compareTo(y) == 0  implies that sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z)) , for all  z .
> - It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required, that  (x.compareTo(y) == 0) == (x.equals(y)).